# Atlassian Stash doesn't work with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket-server

I'm new in Atlassian Stash, I configured a new Atlassian Stash instance. I can clone by HTTP without problems, that now I want to clone the repository by SSH for security.

I have a problem when I clone it, the server asks me SSH keys when I configured the server without keys:

Source Path: ssh://user@ip:port/project/repository.git

The Repository type is in the state "Checking source..." and a Dialog appears:

"Authentication via SSH keys failed, do you want to launch the SSH key agent (Pageant) and retry? (If you don't have an SSH key yet....)

The SSH keys are not active! and I tried to add a private key to the Pageant Key List and doesn't work.

Comment: Have you uploaded your public key to Stash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clone with SSH you need to have added your public key (not the private one!) to the remote Git server, and you need to ensure that your .ssh/ directory and files are not world/group-readable or writable. Try running `ssh` alone to the host/port and get that working first before trying to do anything with `git`.

Comment: Hi AlBlue,

Who have to generate the public key? Each user who wants to connect with the server (with PageAnt, for example)? or the own server (with openssh, for example...) ??? 

Sorry but I'm a bit lost...

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ for a description of how to do this from GitHub. Each user will need to have their own private/public key and upload it to their specific user account. Pagent is a daemon that will unlock a password protected private key; if it is generated with no password then it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, spent around 1-2 hours debugging it and here is my solution for the following assumptions:

- assumption1: you have a gitlub account with 2 step authentication
- assumption2: you have added sourcetree account authenticated with
  oAuth and via SSH
- assumption3: you will need to add new SSH key pair
  in github settings
- assumption4: after having the problem, pageant is
  running in your windows tray, in other words you can see it in the
  bottom right icons dialog

Steps to solve:

1. sourcetree - tools - create or import SSH keys
2. Putty dialog shows up
3. choose key-SHH1 (RSA)
4. choose Parameters -type of key to generate - RSA
5. notice the empty box "No key." click genreate
6. copy the key that appeared in the box
7. go to gitlab - settings (top right), SSH and GPG keys - add SSH key, paste what you copied from the box, click add
8. go back to the putty generator
9. enter passphrase
10. click 'save private key' choose location and filename and save
11. right click on the pageant icon, that is running in your windows tray
12. click 'add key', choose the file saved in step 9
13. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

For me the following configuration worked.
Environment: OS: Windows 8
Git Repo: Stash
Solution: Tools->Options->General->SSH Client Conf -> SSH Client -> Open SSH (from putty/plink)